# averaging across columns with dask

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-processing, dask

I'm a total newbie with dataframes and really struggling with some basic ideas.
I want to take the mean across several columns (x, y, and z motions to get the magnitude, for instance) for each row.
Some dummy data:

```
'time', 'x', 'y', 'z'
1, 1.3, 0.1, 2.2   
2, 1.2, 0.5, 2.0    
3, 1.5, 0.3, 2.0  
4, 1.3, 0.0, 2.5 
5, 1.1, 0.3, 2.3
```

I thought I was onto something with `groupby()` but no dice.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('x', 'y', 'z').mean()
print(grouped_df.head())
```

only prints the original dataframe, so I'm not sure what that function's even doing.

I'm at a total loss for how to move forward, any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't really need `groupby` (the method name can be interpreted differently, but what it does is it groups rows based on the value of the passed columns). Instead, you are looking for `.mean` (without `groupby`):

```py
cols_to_mean = ['x', 'y', 'z']
df['mean_of_cols'] = df[cols_to_mean].mean(axis=1)
df.head()
```

Comment: Had to use `.mean(axis=1)` to account for columns with missing values, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!